# bx slider DestroyShow conflicts with jquery lavaLamp

Tags: jquery, conflict, bxslider, lavalamp

I am having a problem with BX Slider conflicting with LavaLamp.

This is where I am at.

Firstly I have set up my lavalamp menu,

```
//Initialise Lavalamp
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul").lavaLamp({
        speed: 200,
        fx: 'easeOutBack'
    });
});
```

and as I am in Wordpress I have added a line that adds the class 'current' to any menu item with the 'current-menu-item' class.

```
$('.current-menu-item').addClass('current');
```

This all works perfectly...

However I now want the slideshow only to operate if there are more than 3 slides so I have added the code:

```
if (slider.getSlideCount() < 4){
    slider.destroyShow()
    $('.slide').removeClass('active-slide');
    $('.carousel div.gradient-top, .carousel div.gradient-bottom, #controls').css("display","none")
}
```

I have done a bit of poking around and when I take the `slider.destroyShow()` line out everything works fine again, can anyone think of why this is happening or a way around using `destroyShow` to achieve the same effect? I am assuming that when the `destroyShow` command is run it destroys something within the Lavalamp plugin.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is the lack of a semicolon after `slider.destroyShow()` a typo?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment but no that didn't fix it.

Comment: What exactly happens when `slider.destroyShow()` runs? Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: There is one error in the console, it says
Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'children'

How do i check for any further errors.

Comment: Generally, it's best to fix errors when you see them before looking for others. Does the error report say what line number (and file name)?